# Azure B2C custom saml policy: Different claims per App

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0

I followed this manual to register SAML to my azure b2c: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers

With this I am able to define SAML claims in my new TechnicalProfile with for example

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname"/>
```

Now, I have application which expects EXACTLY some attributes with a specific name. Setting PartnerClaimType to some custom string will result in a saml attribute with that string as attribut name:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="LastName" />
```

This will result in:

```
<saml:Attribute Name="LastName"
    NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
    FriendlyName="Surname">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Peters</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
```

But I can just configure claims on that profile - I need to specify it in the app registration in azure.
So the 1st application needs attribute "surname", next needs "FamilyName" and 3rd needs "LastName".

How can I use the claim defined in the policy and change it in the app? I saw there is some property "optionalClaims" in the manifest and there are "saml2Token". But the documentation of this did not helped me (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connecting 3 SAML Relying Parties, you would have 3 Application Registrations, and 3 Relying Party technical profiles as part of your Custom Policy. Each Relying party section would have the required claims mappings.

Comment: So, it is required to create a technical profile for every app which is expecting specific claims?
That's not smart, but thank you for your answer. I will do so.

Comment: Yes that's right. Each Relying Party section is supposed to be for a specific RP (App).

Comment: Thank you. I created very similar technical profiles and use one per app and define the claims there.
Can you tell me why I can define claims in the app registrations itself too?

Comment: These app registrations are technically shared between AAD and AAD B2C. If you use the App Reg config against the AAD endpoints (even of your B2C) tenant, the attributes will be honoured. But in the case of B2C, B2C talks to AAD behind the scenes, and has a static mapping of attributes it will get from it, and will not care about the App Registration config. 2 different STS' and they work differently.